# I Need an Action to Change my NSArray by pressing a button in UIAlertView

Tags: objective-c, indexing, nsmutablearray, uialertview, ibaction

I have a UITableView set up programatically, and it is populated with all the names of the states. When you click on one of the cells, for ex. ALABAMA, a UIAlertView will appear With the title being that of the state you just clicked on (ALABAMA) and a number that correlates to that state, which is in another NSMutable Array. Every state has a different number to correlate with it.

This number is actually a placeholder text in the UIAlert, and the purpose of the alert is so that you can input a number in the text field, and when you hit the CHANGE button, the number that was in the placeholder text (from the Array) will be changed with the number that the user imputed; permanently. All is good until I hit change, and then I get a SIGABRT error, and in output it reads:

`2013-02-21 20:57:33.750 final[10046:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: object cannot be nil'`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                        initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                        message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tax objectAtIndex:53]]
                        delegate:self       
                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"           
                        otherButtonTitles:@"Change", nil];

    UITextField *myTextField =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 50, 200, 25)];
    CGAffineTransform myTransform =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
    [alertView setTransform:myTransform];
    [myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [alertView addSubview:myTextField];
    myTextField.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tax objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
    myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    myTextField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
    myTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    myTextField.delegate = self;


    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex == 1) {

        NSString *theTaxer = [myTextField text];
        [tax replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:theTaxer];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point when alertView:clickedBUttonAtIndex is called `myTextField` is no longer defined since `myTextField` isn't defined as a class ivar you can only reference it in the function you created it in.  If you want to reference `myTextField` elsewhere in your class (in the alertView callback for instance) make it a class iVar.

Answer (score 0):

Shizam is right, I think if you want get the reference of the textview, just give a tag to the textview when you create the alertview like this: myTextField.tag = 111;
and then in the alertView delegate method:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {

    UITextField *textField = [alertView viewWithTag:111];
    NSString *theTaxer = [textField text];
    [tax replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:theTaxer];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
          didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                    initWithTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                    message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tax objectAtIndex:53]]
                    delegate:self       
                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"           
                    otherButtonTitles:@"Change", nil];
alertView.tag =indexPath.row;

UITextField *myTextField =[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 50, 200, 25)];
[myTextField setTag:99];
CGAffineTransform myTransform =CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 0);
[alertView setTransform:myTransform];
[myTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[alertView addSubview:myTextField];
myTextField.placeholder = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [tax objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
myTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
myTextField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
myTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;
myTextField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
myTextField.delegate = self;


[alertView show];
[alertView release];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {
  UITextField * myTextField = (UITextField *)[alertView viewWithTag:99];
    NSString *theTaxer = [myTextField text];
    [tax replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:theTaxer];
}
}
```